# CSS Style Best Practice

Tags: html, css

Is it better to define a single specific class

```
<div class="text_bold_white"> text </div>
```

```css
.text_bold_white {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
```

Or would it be better to separate the styles into 2 classes

```
<div class="text_bold color_white"> text </div>
```

```css
.text_bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.color_white {
    color: white;
}
```

Coming from a programming background, I would lean towards the second, as it allows for reusability. But I have wondered if it would result in too many styles being defined. Could it have rendering performance implications?

Comment: depends on how much your CSS class will be re-used. Normally, breaking into few classes will help re-usability. 1 class for layout (positioning), 1 class for decoration ( color & font, etc )

Comment: Styles are generally used to make a series of edits much easier. The latter example would be a much more complicated way of the HTML equivalent <b> rather than <div class="text_bold"> you generally want to group all the stylized elements into one. IE All headers with their respective styles grouped under .h1 {attributes} and do the same with body elements etc.

Comment: Pretty much the only performance hit will be the extra bytes sent in the HTTP request.  Largely depends on your design.  I'd recommend the second one.

Comment: Speaking of best practice, why is the text in the div bold and white? I would name the class more meaningfully, for example `.image_caption`. Naming classes after css statements isn't much different from writing inline styles.

Comment: @Eoin small detail, `font-weight: strong;` is not valid CSS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the agreed upon best practice is to use semantic classes. So if this is is for example a header of a article, it should look like:

html:

```
<div class="article-header"> text </div>
```

css:

```
.article-header{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

The main reason for this is: you don't want to go into the HTML or code of the website just to remove a `white` and `bold` classes from all your article headers, and add `grey` and `italic`, when you decide bold and white isn't the right style. You want to have a class called `article-header` to edit only the css.

Comment: +1 I totally agree with that. This way you can easily redesign your site without changing your code!

Comment: I think you want to say _bold_ instead of _strong_ ?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie I think you are right. W3 says, there is no strong value in the [font-weight](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) property

Comment: Yes, also I see the error is coming from the OP question!

Comment: Ye sorry, didn't bother to fix it since my point was about semantic css class naming and against doing the whole oocss thing where you apply 30 classes to a element.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me I'd steer away from naming things as `colours` and or `bold` as they are properties of the css class.

If you chose to change you colour from white to red, your css class of `.color_white` is meaningless.

I'd be inclined to named you css classes in a way which describes the role of the styling, like `.footer_text` or `.emphased_link` for example.

Finally, I'd also say that you certainly can come full circle with more semantic classes, if for example you have a very common colour or style you apply often, but in multiple situations, e.g. a colour, font-family, size, combination. It can sometimes be preferable to have a class like:

```
.common_style {
    font-family: some-fonts,
    size: 20px,
    color: #123456;
}
```

Which you can re-use in multiple places, rather than having to write:

```
.header_text {
    font-family: some-fonts;
    size: 20px;
    color: #123456;
}

.footer_text {
    font-family: some-fonts;
    size: 20px;
    color: #123456;
    //then some styles which vary
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

As it gives a nice centralised location to make changes.

Answer (score 1):

The only sense to split it to many classes is reusage of them. For example if you are sure that you will use it again. It makes no sense if class is short but if it's long there is sense in it.

Multiple classes can make it easier to add special effects to elements without having to create a whole new style for that element. For example, you may want to have the ability to float elements to the left or right quickly or add fancy border.

The major disadvantage is when you have multiple classes the code may look messy.

**Example:**

```
<p class="float_l border_fancy clear underline textaligned_left">
```

in such way it's better to create aggregated class.

Comment: fancy_border may contain more things like graphics etc. it's not about how it looks but the sense of it. Sometimes instead of writing `border: 1px solid #777;` people make shortcouts and use classes it's not always good solution

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the usage.

If u want to have specific type of text that will be white and bold u should use one style. If u want to use white only on some bold or bold only some white texts u should use 2 styles.

Also if u want to all the texts to be bold and white I recommend setting it for the paragraph:

```
p {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
```

This will apply on all `<p></p>` tags.

Someone wrote that if u want to use it as paragraph header u should do sth(see some other answer here). I just want to say that it's always better to use header tags - `<h1></h1>`, `<h2></h2>` .. so your code will be **structured** nicely

U can easily edit style of these headers the same way as I wrote above for the paragraph.